# How can I solve the poisson equation in triangualr region?(Exact Solution)

Tags: calculus

I want to solve poisson equations like

$$\nabla^2(V(x,y)) = 0$$
with
$$V(x,0) = 0, V(y+x=a)=b, V(y-x=a)=b$$

so it looks like a triangle with two non-perpendicular (to $x,y$ axis) sides.

But, I forgot how to make a change of variable this case… anyone can help me?

Comment: Your boundary data is not well-defined, e.g. you have $V(a,0)=0$ by your first condition and $V(\pm a,0)=b$ by your last two conditions.Wan you clarify this point?

Comment: Oh we assume all conditions are sliced in an appropriate domain to form a triangle! And I also only need solutions inside the triangle.